# ¿Por qué se manda 0 al enviar un dato decimal?

Tags: c#, mvc

Tengo un detalle con un envío de datos. En mi vista tengo varios inputs, dos de ellos pueden recibir decimales. Si mando número enteros funciona bien la aplicación, el detalle surge cuando estos dos datos tiene un valor decimal y al ser enviados para guardar un registro, me muestran un valor de 0.

Ejemplo. Tengo mi input de **precio**, le escribo el valor de **12.55**, cuando hago la petición para guardar el dato, en mi controlador me sale como **0**, por lo tanto, en mi BD lo guarda como **0**.

Me gustaría saber porque pasa eso.

Esta es mi vista:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">

                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Agregar Concepto</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form>
                        <div style="visibility:hidden">
                            <input type="text" id="mIdcon" disabled="disabled" />
                            <input type="text" id="mIdreq" disabled="disabled" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="row form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <label for="mCanti">Cantidad/ Quantity</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mCanti" placeholder="Cantidad/ Quantity" onkeypress="return filterFloat(event, this);" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-1">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label for="Fent">Fecha de entrega / Delivery Date:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="datefield form-control" id="Fent" placeholder="DD/MM/AAAA" />
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="row form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <label for="UDM">UDM / UOM</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mUDM" maxlength="2" placeholder="UDM / UOM" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-1">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label for="cCta">Cuenta</label>
                                @Html.DropDownList("ctaMAX", null, new { @id = "cCta", @class = "btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle", @style = "color:#777777;background-color:#f8f8f8;border-color:#e7e7e7" })
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="row form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label for="Descripcion">Descripción / Description</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mDes" placeholder="Descripción / Description" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label for="par">Parcialidades/ Partialities</label>
                                @Html.DropDownList("parci", null, new { @id = "par", @class = "btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle", @style = "color:#777777;background-color:#f8f8f8;border-color:#e7e7e7" })

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <label for="NoParte">Numero de parte/ Part Number</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mNopa" placeholder="Numero de parte/ Part Number" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-7">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <label for="Precio">Precio Unitario/ Unit Price</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mPrecio" placeholder="Precio Unitario/ Unit Price" onkeypress="return filterFloat(event, this);" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-7">

                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnAdd" onclick="return AgregarConcepto();">Agregar</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnUpdate" style="display:none;" onclick="ActualizarConcepto();">Modificar</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Este es mi JS

```
function AgregarConcepto() {
var res = Validar();
if (res == false) {
    return false;
}

var ConceptoObj = {
    idconcepto: $('#mIdcon').val(),
    idreq: $('#idreq').val(),
    cantidad: $('#mCanti').val(),
    UDM: $('#mUDM').val(),
    descripcion: $('#mDes').val(),
    NoParte: $('#mNopa').val(),
    precio: $('#mPrecio').val(),
    FechaEntrega: $('#Fent').val(),
    PagoParcial: $('#par option:selected').val()
};
var c = $('#cCta').val();
var f = $('#fes').val();
var m = $('#mon').val();

$.ajax({
    url: '/OrdenCompra/AgregarConcepto?cta=' + c + '&fs=' + f + '&cm=' + m,
    data: JSON.stringify(ConceptoObj),
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        CargarConceptosOC();
        AjusteRate();
        if (result == "-100")
            alert("-Ha superado el limite de conceptos para esta petición");
        if (result == "-200")
            alert("-Ha ocurrido un problema. Contacte al administrador");
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');

    },
    error: function (errormessage) {
        alert(errormessage.responseText);
    }
});
```

}

Este es mi controlador:

```
public JsonResult AgregarConcepto(ConceptosOC conOC, string cta, string fs, string cm)
    {
        int resp = 0, idcon = 0;
        resp = objDB.CUDConceptosOC(conOC, 1);
        DateTime fesol = conOC.FechaEntrega == null ? DateTime.Today : (DateTime)conOC.FechaEntrega;
        DateTime fcenti;

        decimal rate = Convert.ToDecimal(objDB.SelectCadena("Aquí obtengo el valor del dolar"));
        int renglon = Convert.ToInt32(objDB.SelectCadena("Aquí obtengo el renglón que se quiere modificar con base a otros parámetros"));

        if (resp == -1)
        {
            idcon = Convert.ToInt32(objDB.SelectCadena("Aquí obtengo el ID de un registro en específico"));

            switch (conOC.PagoParcial)
            {
                case 2:
                    // ignorar esto
                    break;
                default:
                    resp = objDB.Ejecutar("INSERT INTO CUENTAS(ID_CONCEPTO, ID_PETICION, CANTIDAD, CUENTA, FECHA_REGISTRO, REGISTRO)" +
                        "values(" + idcon + "," + conOC.idreq + "," + ((conOC.cantidad * conOC.precio) * rate).ToString("G", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + ",'" + cta + "','" + fesol.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "'," + (renglon + 1) + ")");
                    break;
            }
        }
        return Json(resp, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Este es mi objeto:

```
public class ConceptosOC
{
    public int idconcepto { get; set; }
    public int idreq { get; set; }
    public decimal cantidad { get; set; }
    public string UDM { get; set; }
    public string descripcion { get; set; }
    public string NoParte { get; set; }
    public decimal precio { get; set; }
    public DateTime? FechaEntrega { get; set; }
    public int PagoParcial { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Porque tu controlador no esta soportando la , como separador decimal, y para el mismo, es un numero mal formado.

Comment: En el objeto ConceptosOC la propiedad precio es de tipo decimal?

Comment: Si, es de tipo decimal. Edité la pregunta para agregar mi objeto.